# Hibernate creates invalid statement while doing insert /update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, informix

I am doing some updates and fixes to an existing system. The application was designed to use Spring 3 and Hibernate 3.

---

The application fails while doing an insert/update into a table; it's using spring - hibernate template.

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(object);
getHibernateTemplate().flush();
```

**Table Structure:**

```
create table user_offer (
     user_id INT,          --FK
     offer_cd CHAR(4),     --FK
     offer_ts TIMESTAMP,
     offer_promo_cd SMALLINT,  --FK
     offer_end_dt DATE,
     offer_by_cd CHAR(10),  
     updated_dt DATE
  )
```

It has simple hibernate mapping file, composite id for PK & basic many-to-one relationship for FKs. I did a quick debug by turning on `<prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>`. The sql generated for insert is just random:

**Query**: `insert into table user_offer(offer_by_cd, offer_ts, updated_dt, offer_cd, offer_promo_cd, offer_end_dt, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

I created the query with sample values and tried manual insert in database. The query fails with the same exception, which is trying to insert string value in the integer column or similar type conversion.

This code was working just fine and we haven't done any changes to this part of the code.

Comment: pls show your mapping

Comment: The issue will be how the values are provided for the 7 placeholder `?` question marks.  The sequence for the columns isn't an obvious one; it is neither alphabetic order nor definition order.  So, the question becomes "how are the values for the placeholders provided", because it appears that one of the codes (offer code or offer by code) is being provided where a numeric value is expected.  I've no idea what could have changed to blow this up.  I know Informix's SQL, but I've no idea what could have changed in the Hibernate/Spring setup.

Comment: Also, it's a bit curious you have a TIMESTAMP column.  Despite everything, that isn't a standard type in Informix — though you could certainly create an approximation to TIMESTAMP with `CREATE DISTINCT TYPE TimeStamp AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND` (or choosing a FRACTION(n) for a fixed number of fractional digits in the seconds).  See [CREATE DISTINCT TYPE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0372.htm) in the manual.